MySQL with recursive table can't reopen issue
I need to query data from Oracle SQL, and use it query in MySQL 8.0.36 server's data
so create temporary table and with recursive table, but always show can't reopen table
and full join temporary table work normally
but show can't reopen table 'b' after using union funtion with with recursive table
if not used union funtion is workable ( query one table ), so how to solve this issue ?
# ==== Create Temporary Table

create temporary table Temp_A ( id integer not null, item varchar(10) not null ) ;
insert into Temp_A ( 1, 'item 1' ),  ( 2, 'item 2' ), ( 3, 'item 3' ) ;

create temporary table Temp_B ( select * from Temp_A ) ;

# ==== Full join Table and Temporary Table to With Recursive Table

with Table_AA as (
  select a.id, a.Col_A, a.Col_AA, b.item from Table_A a left join Temp_A b on a.id = b.id
  union
  select a.id, a.Col_A, a.Col_AA, b.item from Table_A a right join Temp_B b on a.id = b.id
),

Table_BB as (
  select Col_X, Col_Y
  from Table_B
  where id in ( select id from Table_AA )
),

Table_CC as (
  select Col_X, Col_Y
  from Table_C
  where id in ( select id from Table_AA )
)

# ==== union With Recursive Table

select * from Table_BB
union
select * from Table_CC


if select with union funtion then show can't reopen table 'b'
select * from Table_BB union select * from Table_CC

But work normally, if only select select * from Table_BB or select * from Table_CC
select * from Table_BB
select * from Table_CC

this logic in Oracle SQL is workable ( I used similar many times )
Update :
I used json_table by json format data json_table will create tempoaray  table too
and it solve the issue

The published code is not syntactically valid - please fix..

Use bona-fide tables instead of temp tables.

can't use bona-fide tables, need dynamic mapping data
